# Merge between two tables (represented by IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>) with different columns

Tags: c#, .net, performance

My table\grid class is represented by two properties:

```
public class MyTable 
{ 
   public IEnumerable<string> Columns {get;set;} 
   public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Rows {get;set;} 
}
```

So let say I have the following table\grid:

```
ColumnA ColumnB Column C
A1   B1   C1
A2   B2   C2
A3   B3   C3
```

It will be represented by these two properties as follows:

```
Columns = new List<string> {"ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC"};
Rows = new List<IEnumerable<string>>
{
  new List<string>("A1", "B1", "C1"),
  new List<string>("A2", "B2", "C2"),
  new List<string>("A3", "B3", "C3"),
};
```

Until now, merging between two such tables was very easy and efficient, I just used "Concat()" between their Rows properties, and got their "Merged" table with all the data.

Now, my Question is:
In case I need to merge between two such tables with **different columns**, how can I merge them in the most **efficient** way?

Example for merging with different columns:

1. First table:

```
ColumnA ColumnB Column C
A1   B1   C1
A2   B2   C2
A3   B3   C3
```

2. Second table:

```
ColumnB Column D
B4   D4
B5   D5
B6   D6
```

3. Their "merged" table should be:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
A1   B1   C1   null
A2   B2   C2   null
A3   B3   C3   null
null   B4   null   D4
null   B5   null   D5
null   B6   null   D6
```

And of course, it needs to be represented by "Columns" and "Rows" properties as follows:

```
Columns = new List<string> {"ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC", "ColumnD"};

Rows = new List<IEnumerable<string>>
{
  new List<string>{"A1", "B1", "C1", null},
  new List<string>{"A2", "B2", "C2", null},
  new List<string>{"A3", "B3", "C3", null},
  new List<string>{null, "B4", null, "D4"},
  new List<string>{null, "B5", null, "D5"},
  new List<string>{null, "B6", null, "D6"}
};
```

What is the most **efficient** way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you actually had `model` classes to represent your data

Comment: @zaitsman you can assume that these two properties are in a "MyTable" class.

Comment: @Nurial Zrubavely i mena more like `public class Model { public string Column1 {get;set;}}` or similar.

Comment: @zaitsman as I said you can assume there is:
public class MyTable { 
public IEnumerable<string> Columns {get;set;}
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Rows {get;set;}
}

I now also updated my question accordingly

Comment: @Trevor Reid can you please review my question text again?
I made some changes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the idea i came up with.

you can do this with a 2-dimensional array instead but it makes the code ugly in my opinion.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyTable table1 = new MyTable
        {
            Columns = new List<string> { "ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC" },
            Rows = new List<IEnumerable<string>>
            {
                new List<string> {"A1", "B1", "C1"},
                new List<string> {"A2", "B2", "C2"},
                new List<string> {"A3", "B3", "C3"}
            }
        };
        MyTable table2 = new MyTable
        {
            Columns = new List<string> { "ColumnB", "ColumnD" },
            Rows = new List<IEnumerable<string>>
            {
                new List<string> {"B1","D1"},
                new List<string> {"B2","D2"},
                new List<string> {"B3","D3"}
            }
        };
        var result = Merge(table1, table2);
    }

    private static MyTable Merge(MyTable table1, MyTable table2)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> tempTable = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        AddColumns(tempTable, table1);
        AddColumns(tempTable, table2);
        AppendToTable(table1, tempTable);
        AppendToTable(table2, tempTable);

        return ConvertToTable(tempTable);
    }
    private static void AddColumns(Dictionary<string, List<string>> tempTable, MyTable table1)
    {
        foreach (var column in table1.Columns)
        {
            tempTable[column] = new List<string>();
        }
    }
    private static MyTable ConvertToTable(Dictionary<string, List<string>> tempTable)
    {
        MyTable newTable = new MyTable();
        var maxIndex = tempTable.ElementAt(0).Value.Count;

        newTable.Rows = new List<IEnumerable<string>>();
        for (int index = 0; index < maxIndex; index++)
        {
            var newRow = new List<string>();
            foreach (var row in tempTable.Values)
            {
                newRow.Add(row[index]);
            }
            newTable.Rows = newTable.Rows.Append(newRow);
        }
        newTable.Columns = tempTable.Keys;
        return newTable;
    }
    private static void AppendToTable(MyTable table1, Dictionary<string, List<string>> tempTable)
    {
        int rowIndex = tempTable.First().Value.Count + 1;
        foreach (var row in table1.Rows)
        {
            for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row.Count(); cellIndex++)
            {
                string columnName = table1.Columns.ElementAt(cellIndex);
                tempTable[columnName].Add(row.ElementAt(cellIndex));
            }

            FillEmptyCells(tempTable, rowIndex);

            rowIndex++;
        }
    }
    private static void FillEmptyCells(Dictionary<string, List<string>> tempTable, int rowIndex)
    {
        foreach (var row in tempTable.Values)
        {
            if (row.Count < rowIndex)
            {
                row.Add(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the application for this is, but ideally, you would want to take advantage of C#'s type safety.  A string collection is not type-safe.

That being said, C# allows you to create collections with objects of different types by using the **Dynamic** keyword.

Consider the following object types:

```
public class Class1 {
    public string ColumnA {get;set;} 
    public string ColumnB {get;set;}
    public string ColumnC {get;set;}
}

public class Class2 {
    public string ColumnD {get;set;} 
    public string ColumnE {get;set;}
    public string ColumnF {get;set;}
}
```

With these types in hand you can use the dynamic keyword to do the following:

```
var list = new List<dynamic>();
list.Add(new Class1(){ColumnA = "TestColumnA"});
list.Add(new Class2(){ColumnD = "TestColumnD"});
Console.WriteLine(list[0].ColumnA.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(list[1].ColumnD.ToString());
for(var i =0; i< list.Count; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(list[i].GetType().Name);            
  Console.WriteLine($"IsComponentA: {list[i] is Class1}");
}
```

If you absolutely have to go the string collection route, then the Dynamic keyword will still work.

I created a dotnet fiddle so you can see this in action:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/lyucN2.

-Isaac

Comment: @Issac Martinez
Thanks but I didn't understand how it solve my problem :)
I need a code which merges two such tables :)